# PyYAML can't parse sequence of sequences

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

This is valid YAML:

```
jobs:
  - type: Agricultural
```

This is not valid YAML:

```
jobs:
  - type: Agricultural
    - title: Farmer
```

Why not? In PyYAML, this yields:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "jobs.yaml", line 2, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '-'
  in "jobs.yaml", line 3, column 5
```

Comment: The key `type` can not have two values: `Agriculture` and a list. Your YAML is not valid.

Comment: How do you make it valid?  My intention is to list jobs of different categories and titles.  Many possible categories, many different titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is invalid is because you are trying have a node that consists of both a mapping and a sequence and that is not allowed within YAML, where a node is either one of these composites, or a primitive.

The mapping in case only has the key value pair (`type`, `Agricultural`), the sequence contains the mapping (with key `title`)

There are multiple ways to change that into valid YAML, here are some:

- you can leave out the `type` key and use `agricultural` as a key for the nested list:

  ```
  jobs:
    - Agricultural:
      - title: Farmer
  ```
- you might not need the nested sequence:

  ```
  jobs:
    - Agricultural:
      title: Farmer
  ```
- you can use tags, which allow you to directly load the proper underlying class instead of checking for the string `Agricultural` yourself:

  ```
  jobs:
    - @Agricultural
      title: Farmer
  ```

The latter needs an appropriate class registered, but is IMO the best solution if you have multiple jobs (sub)types.

Answer (score 1):

an example of something that would be valid and like what you want:

```
--- 
jobs: 
  - type: agricultural
    titles: 
      - Farmer
      - Picker
      - Combine Operator
   - type: manufacturing
     titles:
       - assembler
       - shipper
       - shop forman
```

Comment: But I don't want to repeat "type: agricultural" all over the place - I want to group jobs by categories.

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: I want to know why my above solution doesn't work though.  If a job can have many '- type's, why can't a 'type' have many '- title's?

Comment: Your thinking about it wrong.  the way its represented there its.... The jobs has a list of things delineated by the - (dash) one per entry in the list.   Then each entry in the list has a set of keys those keys have values that can be either a simple value (number, string, boolean), a list of things, or another set of keys with values.  If you read this into python in my example you would have:  base['jobs'][0]['titles'][0]   Its the syntax of what a yaml entry can contain.  it can't have that naked - title   there is nothing in the list entry to use to refer to it with.

Comment: Another way of thinking of it is you told yml that the list entry is a dict by using the key value syntax.  you need to continue to use that for  the next line.  it is expecting a key at the point it gets the - titles

Comment: Any questions remaining? @alex